# Will this javascript do anything or is it incomplete?

Tags: javascript, widget

I've been asked to include the following javascript in a project to make a widget appear:

```
<div class="nd-service nd-tyre-booking">
<script type="text/javascript">
var sourceDir = 'js/widgets/';
var widget = [
            'http://<company-domain-is-here>.co.uk/', 
            sourceDir, 
              ['tyre-booking', '4a68ff678d3d8fae7615519c977e5a5490cca00b']
           ];

var s = 'script', o = document.createElement(s);
o.type = 'text/javascript';
o.src = widget[0] + widget[1] + 'lib/require.js?';
o.setAttribute('data-main', widget[0] + widget[1]
document.getElementsByTagName(s)[0].parentNode.appendChild(o);</script>
```

Nothing happens though. I don't really know any javascript but it looks incomplete to me. It's referring to directories/files that don't exist such as `js/widgets/` and `lib/require.js`

I've been back and forth with them asking for any kind of documentation and confirming that this is all that's required to make the widget appear, but they insist that it just needs to be pasted somewhere in the body and then it'll appear.

My javascript console outputs `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` on the final line of javascript.

Comment: You should be able to identify the line causing an error when the `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` error message apears. Which line is it in the code above ?

Comment: There seems to be a missing parentheses at the end of the penultimate line, which would make the last line's 'document' an unexpected identifier.

Comment: `o.setAttribute('data-main', widget[0] + widget[1])` ? missing `)` at the end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line .setAttribute('data-main', widget[0] + widget[1] misses ")" and a ";".

It should be o.setAttribute('data-main', widget[0] + widget[1]);

And about the "does the script do anything" part, yes, it does. It defines a new script, fills it with something but... I fail to see the part where it is appended to the body.

Comment: Thanks, can you give me an example of how I would append the widget to the body?

Comment: Edit: Use this, it is better document.body.appendChild(s); Also, should be called before the last line.